# How to close CMD when another program is exited?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to close a cmd window when the program csgo.exe is exited. There is one cmd window open, which is ( node server.js ) and I would like the program to be stopped when csgo.exe is quit.

Here is the full .bat.

```
@ECHO OFF
start steam://rungameid/730
start cmd /K "cd C:\CSGO-HUD-master & node server.js"
start cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox & start firefox.exe http://localhost:2626/ & exit"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Change `start /K` to `start /C`

Comment: start/C exits after the command is carried out, but I want the .bat to make the .cmd exit when another program is exited. Not sure if it's entirely possible in batch.

Comment: Are you talking about `start "" /WAIT cmd /C [...]`?

Comment: @SomethingDark, you actually mean `start cmd /C`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The is doable if you know the task name of the program you want to watch. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
tasklist|findstr calc.exe > nul
if %errorlevel%==1 goto ENDLOOP
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
goto LOOP
:ENDLOOP
exit
```

In this example we want our bat to terminate after the calculator (calc.exe) is closed.

To achieve this, we first execute `tasklist` which gives us a list of all running programs. Then we check the output for the occurrence of `calc.exe`. If it is still running, `findstr calc.exe` will set `%errorlevel%` to `0` so we can just jump back and check again. If `calc.exe` is not running, `%errorlevel%` will be set to `1` so we know that we can jump out of the loop and terminate.

I've added the line `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul` to avoid [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). This line will make your code "wait" for one second between two iterations. Consider that to adjust the waiting time you'll have to replace `2` by the desired amount of seconds to wait **+1**. So if you want to wait for five seconds the code would be `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul`.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried putting it into my pre-existing batch file but I'm struggling to find where I can put it to make it work. Would I put it after an & in after the node server.js? I just need it to shut the cmd.exe that's open.

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your bat.

Comment: It's in the original post.